# Error Remote 'Bitbucket' does not exist in the repository in vs2017

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket, visual-studio-2017

Why does I get this error in Vs2017 when trying to push my commit to bitbucket.
I don't get this error when pushing from vs2015.

Comment: Is the remote repository still available? (i.e., does it show in the list when you run `git remote`?) If not, you can try adding it back manually: `git remote add Bitbucket [bitbucket-repository-clone-url]`.

Comment: Hi @Dekker , Yes it exist, I can push to same repository from VS2015.